# Google Calendar - Is there a non-manual method for moving events from one calendar to another?

Tags: google-calendar

I would like to move a few dozen events from one calendar to another.

Is there a way to do this, without having to delete each event and re-create them on the new calendar?

**Clarification**

By `non-manual method`, I mean not having to delete each event, then having to recreate each event with descriptions, times, invitations, etc. Perhaps this wording was poor, but the accepted answer does utilize Google's system for moving an event rather than me having to simulate the effect via delete/create.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you edit the event, you can change which calendar it is on:

[image]

Comment: I did not see this, because I did not have the second calendar setup yet. However, I see it now!

Comment: Hm, that still involves editing each entry separately..

Comment: @slhck But it *doesn't* involve deleting each event and recreating it on the other calendar. I have not yet investigated the possibility of using Google Apps Script or the API ...

Comment: @slhck It does not involve deleted and re-entering the events with each description / invitation list, etc. I will edit my question to be a bit more clear in that respect

Comment: @hamlin11 Oh, okay. Well I thought about using a desktop calendar software or something, but if @Williams answer works out for you, that's fine :)